# React router dom 6 route structure with layouts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have this page structure

- login (Root page)
- forget password
- dashboard (Wrapper layout needed)
- orders (Wrapper layout needed)

The orders page and Dashboard needed the wrapper layout.

Right now I have this code

```
const routes = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<RootLayout />}>
      <Route path="orders" element={<Orders />} />
      <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
    </Route>
  )
);
```

And this is root layout

```
export default function RootLayout() {
  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <h1>This top header</h1>
      </header>
       
      <main>
        <Outlet/>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I am unsure how I can add Login page to the root path and Forget password page to the `"/forget-password"` path. `RootLayout` should not wrap in those two pages as well.

I have tried this approach even though it is adding a extra `"/app"` part. But this also not working as intended

```
createRoutesFromElements(
  <Route path="/" element={<Login  />}>
    <Route path="app" element={<RootLayout />}>
      <Route path="orders" element={<Orders />} />
      <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
)
```

How can I achieve this with `react-router-dom@6`?

Answer (score 4):

`createRoutesFromElements` expects a single React node. Render a single "outer" route on `"/"` with no element which will render an `Outlet` by default. "RootLayout" is a layout route and doesn't need to participate in the route path matching, omit the `path="app"` prop.

```
createRoutesFromElements(
  <Route path="/">
    <Route index element={<Login />} /> // <-- "/"
    <Route
      path="forgot-password             // <-- "/forgot-password"
      element={<ForgotPassword />}
    />

    <Route element={<RootLayout />}>
      <Route
        path="orders"                   // <-- "/orders"
        element={<Orders />}
      />
      <Route
        path="dashboard"                // <-- "/dashboard"
        element={<Dashboard />}
      />
    </Route>
  </Route>
)
```